# Where is my weth gone

Tags: etherscan, arbitrum

[image]

I have converted arbitration eth to weth but it is not showing in Uniswap wallet

Comment: Some wallets don't show tokens automatically. Try to find a way to import it. Also you can check your WETH balance on arbiscan.

Comment: Can you share the transaction hash?